# Hot Encoding w.r.t to reference (last lexicographically sorted element of the column)

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, encoding

My column looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'A':['a','b','a','c','b','d','a']
        })
```

```
   A
0  a
1  b
2  a
3  c
4  b
5  d
6  a
```

I need to lexicographically sort the column and then start with the hot-encoding process but I have to take the last value of that column as the reference (should be mapped to a vector of all zeros) and replace them in the "A" column.

Like:

```
a = [1 0 0] 
b = [0 1 0]
c = [0 0 1]
d = [0 0 0]
```

and the final result should look like this

```
   A
0  [1 0 0] 
1  [0 1 0]
2  [1 0 0] 
3  [0 0 1]
4  [0 1 0]
5  [0 0 0]
6  [1 0 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `get_dummies`

```
df['A'] = df.A.str.get_dummies().drop('d', axis=1).to_numpy().tolist()
df
Out[237]: 
           A
0  [1, 0, 0]
1  [0, 1, 0]
2  [1, 0, 0]
3  [0, 0, 1]
4  [0, 1, 0]
5  [0, 0, 0]
6  [1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but can you explain how this works? I am kind of confused.

Comment: check what is dummies variable :-)